# Modifying UIImageView while being used in background thread?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` that I'm animating (using `UIView`'s `commitAnimations`) and I'm moving it using `NSObject`'s `performSelectorInBackground:` for better performance.  Now my question is, is it okay to change of modify the image in the `UIImageView` while it is moving using a separate thread? Everything seems to run okay, but I wanted to ask because I know you're supposed to copy data for when starting new threads.

I'm using `UIImageView`'s `setImage:`, which isn't documented but works.  Would it be better to use `UIImageView.image` property?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting a property is equivalent to invoking its corresponding setter method. It's documented, you just haven't noticed it: having a (read-write) property named 'image' implicitly means having an

```
- (UIImage *)image;
```

and a

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)img;
```

method.

---

You should always perform UI operations on the main thread. Even if it works now, it may break once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)  So you're saying I should use commitAnimations: only on the main thread?  What about calling UIView's - (void)display method on a background thread?